# Do I need UK transit visa to move from Terminal 3 to Terminal 5 Heathrow?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, lhr

I (Indonesian) have a possible travel itinerary from Japan to Berlin via UK Heathrow airport. From the airline website it says that I need to move from Terminal 3 (arrival from Japan) to Terminal 5 of Heathrow airport. As I have never been to Heathrow before, do I need to pass the border check/immigration? If so then  do I need to have UK transit visa or some sort? I have residence permit visa for Germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as an Indonesian citizen traveling through Heathrow air-side to another country you do not have to pass through border check/immigration and hence do not require a transit visa.

[I need to change terminals at Heathrow. Can I transit airside?](https://ukimmigrationspecialist.com/2012/08/25/i-need-to-change-terminals-at-heathrow-can-i-transit-airside/)

> Heathrow’s terminals are connected by dedicated buses that transport
>   passengers from one terminal to another airside. If your baggage has
>   been checked through to your final destination, you will not have to
>   pass UK immigration control; the buses are part of the airport’s
>   internal airside transit system.

and

[UK.GOV](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/ghana/transit/somewhere_else)

> You always pass through border control if you:
>
> - **leave the main airport building for any reason**
> - need to collect your bags and check them in to your onward flight
>
> You must also pass through border control if both:
>
> - your onward flight leaves on a different calendar day to when you arrive
> - there’s nowhere for you to stay overnight in the airport, for example in a transit hotel

Comment: does that mean that moving from terminal 3 to 5 itself is happening inside the airport thus no need for passing UK immigration control? also could you provide the links for both quote? thanks!

Comment: @ihsan Haikal Yes, exactly: staying airside, one may transfer between Heathrow terminals without passing UK immigration. Links for the two quotes are in Honorary World Citizen's answer, each link is just above the quoted text

Comment: @skifans Fair enough, I've deleted my Answer. Thanks for the nudge.